# iOS 7 list of notifications deletes after some period of time

Tags: ios7, apple-push-notifications, lockscreen

My problem is that after some period of time (near 10 minutes), notification list of my app erase unexpectedly and badge clear too. Probably it's connected with background update because my time interval to update is equal 10 min. But my log's didn't show this.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was connected with method :

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Because in this method I have erased my badges, so if you unlock your phone after long period of time it calls automatically if you app in background. So, I have solved this issue when move erase logic to

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```